# JVM crashes without any core file generated

Tags: java, jvm

Usually when ever my jvm crashes it generate the core file, but for one incident it doesn't generated the core file, didn't got any clue ?

Why the Jvm crash the core file is not generated

Comment: what is this one incident? what is the code trying to do? how far does it get?

Comment: Is there a reason you tell us this most interesting story?

Comment: Maybe it crashed while it was creating the core file from the crash.

Comment: Why the Jvm crash the core file is not generated

Answer (score 1):

There's too little information in your post to give a good answer. Nevertheless, the first thing I'd check would be the `ulimit -c` setting in the relevant environment, since the creation of core files is controlled by the OS, not by the JVM.